# uploading binary

Tags: iphone

I get warning: Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was 
not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011) can anyone help me ...ive been stuck
for a month ...also the app goes on my device for testing and i get a file to zip in my build
iphoneos file but when i use the app loader it says: Directory Services reported the following
error: Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly. (-20101)...i don't know how this happens when i log in correctly.. please help someone thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive "Directory Services reported the following error: Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly. (-20101)" from Application Loader, this means that your username and/or password has changed or it's in correct.

Solution: 
1)Open Application Loader.
2)Click Window->Run Setup Wizard (Shift-Command-S). 
3)Read the information on below the "Welcome to Application Loader." text 
4)Click "Next".
5)Enter your iTunes Connect information (Apple ID and Password). If there are multiple developers on the account, use the Team Lead/Agent account information.
6) Click "Next".
7) If the information is correct you will get "Your iTunes login information has been verified." and if not you will get the same error as before and you will can always go back to re-enter the correct iTunes Connect information (Apple ID and Password).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a build for submitting (Release) to the app store, in Xcode under project properties ensure you have the settings for Release/Distribution  selected. Then in the certificate row check you have your distribution certificate selected.

In Organizer check that your certificate is still valid. If not use your web browser and update the distribution certificate under developer.apple.com. THe update certificate takes a few minutes to become available. Back in Xcode use the update in Organizer to load your new certificates. If you get an error logging in then Xcode probably remembers an old or wrong password.

When you have your certificated sorted out, and want to do a build for the store use "Build and Archive" to upload your binary to Apple. The app loader still exists but since Xcode 3.2.something this functionality is included in Xcode

Answer (score -2):

The best solution would be to develop for the Android. However, failing that are you using the Application Loader, not the xCode one which no longer works.

Also have you created your own Provisioning profiles for release and using them when you archive your code into its zip file from within Xcode?

Comment: other OS's have nothing to do with the question. Why want to start a flame war?

Comment: ok iam noobee, i have rebuilt the app on a new project file the build succeeds find on the simulator but when i go to distribution on device it get the message: Check dependencies [BEROR] Code Sign error: a valid provisioning profile matching the application Identifier 'ZC7F86AH6T.com.yourcompany.ThaiGirls' could not be found